# API Gateway not returning Response

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-api-gateway

I was trying GCP API Gateway using firebase authentication. I can see my request has been processed from the logs and completed with response code 200. However, I am not getting the response back to my client. I am getting the response when I call the function directly. Am I missing something ?

**API Config**

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: API Endpoints
  description: API Endpoints
  version: 1.0.1
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
securityDefinitions:
  firebase:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/my-project"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "my-project"
paths:
  /hello:
    get:
      summary: Test link
      operationId: hello
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/hello
      security:
        - firebase: []
      responses:
        "200":
          description: A successful response
          schema:
            type: string
        "403":
          description: Failed to authenticate
```

**Function**

```
 * Responds to any HTTP request.
 *
 * @param {!express:Request} req HTTP request context.
 * @param {!express:Response} res HTTP response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

**Logs**

[image: Logs]

**Additional Query**
Initially, I had my functions private and was getting 403. It gave me 200 once I added `allUsers` with `Cloud Functions Invoker` to the permissions to the function I am trying to invoke. So I am a bit confused here. Part of the reason I am using API gateway with `firebase` `auth` is to protect it against unauthorised calls. And for `firebase` `auth` to work, I had to add `allUsers`, making it public. My understanding was that the API gateway alone would be public while all the backend services that it invokes would be private. In this case, the function can be directly invoked by anyone, rendering API Gateway useless. How can I setup the backend to private and only respond to authenticated calls through API gateway ?

**Additional Logs**

```
{
 insertId: "8c13b49c-2752-4216-8188-d445f4724ef14850908905639612439@a1"  
 jsonPayload: {
  api_key_state: "NOT CHECKED"   
  api_method: "1.myapi.GenerateRTCToken"   
  api_name: "1.myapi"   
  api_version: "1.0.1"   
  client_ip: "999.999.999.999"   
  http_method: "GET"   
  http_response_code: 200   
  location: "us-central1"   
  log_message: "1.myapi.GenerateRTCToken is called"   
  producer_project_id: "myproject"   
  request_latency_in_ms: 161   
  request_size_in_bytes: 4020   
  response_size_in_bytes: 579   
  service_agent: "ESPv2/2.17.0"   
  service_config_id: "myapi-config"   
  timestamp: 1606313914.9804168   
  url: "/generateRTCToken"   
 }
 logName: "projects/myproject/logs/myapi%2Fendpoints_log"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-11-25T14:18:36.521292489Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   location: "us-central1"    
   method: "1.myapi.GenerateRTCToken"    
   project_id: "myproject"    
   service: "myapi"    
   version: "1.0.1"    
  }
  type: "api"   
 }
 severity: "INFO"  
 timestamp: "2020-11-25T14:18:34.980416865Z"  
}
```

Comment: did you try to follow the official documentation? https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quickstart-console

Comment: Yes. I am not using API key as mentioned in the documentation. Instead I am using firebase auth. It really doesn't tell me why I wouldn't recieved a response nor it does answer my second question.

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting any response back"? Does it hang? For how long? Any eventual error?

Comment: Yes it waits for the response and times out eventually.

Comment: I see this as possibly two issues mixed: one being not getting an answer at all, and the other one might be something with permissions within the project( this is why you needed to make the functions public). Are the functions deployed from the GCP project or from the firebase project?

Comment: about not getting a response at all, 1) could you share the api-gateway logs?  2) when calling the cloud function directly do you get any response?

Comment: 1. 
`2020-11-25 00:53:59.184 EST
us-central1
200
1.2 s
1.quadlii_api_1vss1kcaz7bkf_apigateway_fan_demand_cloud_goog.GenerateRTCToken is called`

Log from API Gateway suggests the response was returned.
Response Code was 200

2. Yes

The function is public. I still havenet figured out how to make it private and still invoke it for authenticated users. See my `Additional Query` in the question

Comment: I posted an answer for the functions needing to be public,
If you need firther help with the functions not having an answer you can pubish a new question or share the full logs so we have more debugging info to help you.

Comment: I have added the logs as well. I couldn't find anything from the logs other than the fact that it return 200. Is the gateway interfering with the proxy to send the response back to the sender ?

Comment: @SoniSol can you please check the logs and let me know if more info?

Answer (score 3):

To call the `Google Cloud Function` from the `Api-Gateway` without making it public you can grant the service account used by the `API-Gateway` the role `CloudFunctions Invoker`

On [Creating an API config (4)](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/quickstart#creating_an_api_config) : you set a service Account, take note of this service account.

Once you have identified the service account you can grant it the `Cloud Funtions Invoker` role to the service account. For these you can follow these steps:

- Go to [IAM&Admin](https://console.cloud.google.com//iam-admin/iam)
- Look for the service account, and click on the pencil next to it( If you don't see the service account click on Add and type the service account email)
- For role Select `Cloud Functions Invoker`
- Click on Save

This will grant the service account the permission to call the functions without having them public.

Comment: Answers my additional query

Answer (score 1):

I have an similar issue with API Gateway throwing the same response validating a token against keycloak.

The issue was with the JWT, it was too long, we remove unused roles from the user and work perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [document](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-firebase) where it is explained in detail how to use Firebase to authenticate in API Gateway.

In general there are two conditions that we need to keep on mind in order to configure these services:

When your client application sends an HTTP request, the authorization header in the request must contain the following JWT claims:

- iss (issuer)
- sub (subject)
- aud (audience)
- iat (issued at)
- exp (expiration time)

To support Firebase authentication, add the following to the security definition in your API config:

```
securityDefinitions:
    firebase:
      authorizationUrl: ""
      flow: "implicit"
      type: "oauth2"
      # Replace YOUR-PROJECT-ID with your project ID
      x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
      x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
      x-google-audiences: "YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
```

Comment: Sorry it doesn't answer my question. I am able to authenticate and trigger the function or service. But I am not receiving any response back.